# Return type name colliding with method name in C++

Tags: c++

I'm looking for an explanation why the following code does not compile on Windows:

```
class TypeA {};

class TypeBInterface
{
public:
    ~TypeBInterface() {}
    virtual TypeA& TypeA() = 0;
};

class TypeB : public TypeBInterface
{
public:
    TypeA& TypeA() { return mTypeA; }
private:
    TypeA mTypeA;
};
```

There is some sort of naming collision between the return type `TypeA` and the method name `TypeA`. The following return type works fine:

```
::TypeA& TypeA() { return mTypeA; }
```

I don't understand the C++ rules that are causing this behavior. Could I get a simple explanation?

---

**Edit:** @BalogPal requested more context. I am using method chaining to build up a map object. In order to add keys and values I can do `lMap.Key(1).Value(2).Key(3).Value(4);`. `Key()` creates a new `Key` object, adds it to the map, and returns a `Key&` reference to the new key. Perhaps I will get rid of the explicit `Key` type later, but for now that's what I have. I like the brevity of `Key()` versus something like `CreateKey()`, and I think it is very understandable what it does in this context.

Comment: That would hardly pass a review, please do yourself a favor and give the method dome sensible name. Or make it an explicit conversion operator

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Did you mean to write a conversion operator that allows implicit or explicit conversion from TypeB to TypeA like TypeA() { return mTypeA;} ?

Comment: @BalogPal You don't know the context of the problem; the above is a contrived example. In the actual code I think the name is sensible. I am not trying to do any conversion.

Comment: then please edit the question adding that code showing usage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TypeBInterface` is ill-formed, but no diagnostic is required from the compiler, I think. The issue is that the first time it sees `TypeA` in the return type, it looks it up, sees nothing in the class, and then finds the class. However, there's a rule in C++ that says that every identifier used in a class definition must still mean the same thing at the end of the class definition. However, if you look up `TypeA` after the method declaration, it will find the method, not the type, so the meaning changed.

`TypeB` is just invalid. When it sees `TypeA` in the return type location, lookup will find the function `TypeBInterface::TypeA`, which is not a type.

Solution: don't do that.

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't do `::TypeA& TypeA() {}`, or just that I can't do `TypeA& TypeA() {}` since the compiler won't accept it?

Comment: Well, you definitely shouldn't do the latter. The former is probably not a very good idea either, but it depends on your use case.

Comment: @M.Dudley He's saying that the method's name cannot be "TypeA".

Comment: I think the :: qualified code is valid, but it must be applied everywhere consistently, like at `::TypeA mTypeA;` too. But it would have hard time on a review even if works

Comment: [basic.scope.class/]1 "A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in
the completed scope of `S`. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule."

Answer (score 1):

As the problem is around hiding names, you indeed must use the fully qualified name for the type, alternatively create a typedef that dodges the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, that code is syntactically invalid.  As a hard rule, you should never have a method with the same name as a class/type, except for constructors.

Comment: Are you sure? I have never heard that rule before. "You may never give a method and a class the same name" seems awfully restrictive.

Comment: @M.Dudley Yes, I am sure.  At any rate, even if the compiler allowed it, I would advise against programming it that way because it is more difficult to read.  And I know that some would argue otherwise.  But really, any time you have multiple things that are written exactly the same but don't mean the same thing, it is going cause confusion.